# High density memory problem

Tags: ram

I'm updating RAM card from 1GB Single Density to 2GB High Density on a Compaq Presario PC SG3310LA (AMD Athlon 4050e X2) running Lubuntu 16.04 desktop. After a while (less than 5 ') it freezes (no message on screen) or simply reboots. Memtest86+ after 7+ hours of test showed no errors.
And the strangest thing, on the same machine in another partition I have Win XP which works perfectly fine.

I've restored the old 1GB SD memory card and it returned to normal ...

Where could it be the problem?
Any suggestion is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Have you confirmed the new RAM's compatibility with the computer? No, just because it works *sometimes* does not mean it's compatible.

Comment: Did this problem begin after the installation of the new RAM? Did this ever happen with 1G RAM? How much total RAM? How much swap?

Comment: @heynnema Yes the problem begin with the new RAM never happen before. This card is the total RAM  I mean just 1 card. Swap sapce is in its own 4GB partition

Comment: Go to crucial.com and confirm that you've got the correct 2G RAM stick for your model computer. It's a RAM stick problem.

Comment: @fkraiem I was told is compatible, but I don't know how to probe that...

Comment: Crucial.com is offering me up to 2GB DDR2 PC2-6400 • Unbuffered • NON-ECC. From that point of view is compatible.  But, how is it possible that in win XP it was working ok and not in Lubuntu 16.04?